# download url in txt format into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, urllib

I am having trouble trying to download the data from this particular URL and store it in a pandas data-frame.  Can anyone help with this?

```
url ='http://www2.conectiv.com/cpd/tps/archives/nj/2017/12/20171205NJA1.txt'
```

I need to store each `Segment` as a row with corresponding numbers in separate columns.  so, I need it in this format:

```
NJAAP, 12/5/2017, 37.63, 36.34, 35.97,..., 38.52
NJAAS, 12/5/2017, 37.63, 36.34, ...        etc
```

I tried the following method:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen

df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=4)
```

But, I am not getting what i wanted.  I am getting this instead:

```
Segment:NJAAP 12/05/2017 37.63 36.34 35.97 35.76 36.71 39.90 46.36 52.49 56.16 58.41 58.98 59.60 59.58 58.52 57.40 54.34 53.90 53.15 51.44 49.49 46.96 44.12 41.02 38.52
0   Segment:NJAAS 12/05/2017 ...
1   Segment:NJADC 12/05/2017 ...
2   Segment:NJAGN 12/05/2017 ...
3   Segment:NJAGT 12/05/2017 ...
```

Can someone please help?  Thanks

Comment: [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has many useful options - use them. (for example `header=None`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has many useful options

- `header=None` - and first row is not treated as headers.
- `sep='\s+'` - and it uses spaces to split columns (instead of comma `,`). It is regex.

.

```
import pandas as pd

url ='http://www2.conectiv.com/cpd/tps/archives/nj/2017/12/20171205NJA1.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=4, header=None, sep='\s+')
```

After you load data you can change values in columns.

This removes `Segments:` in first column

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('Segment:', '')
```

Comment: read_csv has other useful options - ie. `sep` to separate columns.

Comment: I added `sep='\s+'` in example.

Comment: btw, so my final answer is in a series where each index is given by date, and the numbers...how do i split this into a dataframe eventually? i.e Series[0] = NJAAP, 12/05/2017, 37.63 etc

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question (using button `Add Question`) and add all useful informations (and examples).

Comment: never mind..i got it.  I will update the answer above :)

Comment: NEVER CHANGE ANSWERS.

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question - this is how Stackoverflow works - it is not forum.